# how to fix resolved state in apache felix?

Tags: java, cmd, osgi-bundle, apache-felix

this is the codes and [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh930.png) seems like...

```
g! lb 
START LEVEL 1
 ID|State  |Level|Name 
  0|Active |    0|System Bundle (4.0.3)
  1|Active |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (1.6.6) 
  2|Active |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.12.0) 
  3|Active |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.10.0)
  4|Active |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
  6|Installed | 1|Service Tracker-based dictionary client (1.0.0)
  7|Installed | 1|English dictionary (1.0.0) 
g! start 7 
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle \[7\]. 
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2027) 
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1895) 
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Basic.start(Basic.java:729) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:137) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:82) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Console.run(Console.java:62) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.console(Shell.java:203) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.gosh(Shell.java:128) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:137) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:82) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89) 
at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Activator.run(Activator.java:75)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: tutorial/example2/Activator has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2128) 
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1432) 
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72) 
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1317) 
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.createBundleActivator(Felix.java:4170) 
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1972) 
... 32 more java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:

tutorial/example2/Activator has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0),

this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Comment: click the error code for screenshot

Comment: No, I'm too lazy. Provide a [mcve] and learn [ask] and I'll reconsider ;-). Just posting some code and/or error snapshots is not enough, you need to provide much more detail (we can't know what you want exactly)...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all !
and thank you  @aschipfl for the comment.since i'm new to that.
problem solved..
what i did was remove old versions of java.and re install new stable versions.
the problem was i'm compiling classes to a new version (version 53) but unfortunately
jre support only for upto version 52